# TextField is covered by iOS virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

Hi I have a UItextField inside a cell and it is covered by the virtual keyboard when it starts editing. This is a JSON representation I made up to illustrate the components in my viewController

```
MyViewController : {     
     UIView : {
          UIView : {
               height : 100
          },
          UITableView : {
               cell1 : myCell,
               cell2 : myCell,
               cell3 : myCell,
               cell4 : {
                            UITextField
                       }
          }
     }
}
```

What should I do so that the view scrolls up when I start editing the TextField ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard practice is to use a scroll view to scroll the contents of your view when the keyboard is visible. Apple provides codes sample in their document [Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html):

> Listing 5-3  Adjusting the frame of the content view and scrolling a
>   field above the keyboard
>
> ```
> - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
>
>     NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
>
>     CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
>
>     CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
>
>     bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
>
>     [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
>
>     [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
> ```
>
> }

There are additional steps required to register for keyboard notifications, all included in the document mentioned.

There are other methods mentioned in the doc, none of which are automatic. Sometimes, when such basic functionality requires additional code, such as this, we're reminded that there's room for improvement yet with Apple's development tools.

Answer (score 0):

You want to adjust the content insets of your impacted view when the keyboard is about to display. Then reset it back to 0 once the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: Shouldn't this not need my intervention ?

Comment: It should absolutely need your intervention. Because the keyboard is a window displayed *above* your views and disjoint from your application, it is up to your application to move views accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get notification from the iOS when the keyboard is appeared.

In viewDidLoad you can register your VC to observ:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Now your keyboardWillShown: methods will be called when keyboard will appear.
In keyboardWillShown: method you want to change your tableViews contentInset. This is how you do:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    self.keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,self.keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    [self scrollToContent];
}
```

Now you changed your tableViews contentInset and you saved the keyboards size to a property (keyboardSize) but it is not checked that your content is visible. In the last line I called the scrollToContent method which scroll the tableView to the required position:

```
-(void)scrollToShowActiveField {
    //your views size
    CGRect myViewRect = self.view.frame;
    //substract the keyboards size
    myViewRect.size.height -= self.kbSize.height;

    //offsettedFrame is your UITextView
    CGRect offsettedFrame = self.activeField.frame;

    //we want to see some "padding" between the textview and the keyboard so I add some padding
    offsettedFrame.origin.y += 100;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(myViewRect, offsettedFrame.origin) ) {
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:offsettedFrame animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I assumed that your UITableView has a fullscreen size. If not, then you need to adjust the contentInset size to your needs.